# Separate different elements after using .find_all in Beautiful Soup

Tags: html, string, web, beautifulsoup

I am a bit of an amateur using `BeautifulSoup`. After running `soup.find_all('ul',class_='tags tags--project')` in my object of interest I obtain the following output:

```html
<ul class="tags tags--project">
<li><a href="/processes/mes-idees-pour-mon-quartier/f/472/budgets/3/projects?filter%5Bcategory_id%5D%5B%5D=80" title="Filtrer les résultats de la catégorie : Nature en ville"><span class="show-for-sr">Filtrer les résultats de la catégorie : Nature en ville</span><span aria-hidden="true">Nature en ville</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/processes/mes-idees-pour-mon-quartier/f/472/budgets/3/projects?filter%5Bscope_id%5D%5B%5D=71" title="Filtrer les résultats pour le secteur : 4.2 - Jolimont / Soupetard / Roseraie / Gloire / Gramont / Amouroux"><span class="show-for-sr">Filtrer les résultats pour le secteur : 4.2 - Jolimont / Soupetard / Roseraie / Gloire / Gramont / Amouroux</span><span aria-hidden="true">4.2 - Jolimont / Soupetard / Roseraie / Gloire / Gramont / Amouroux</span></a></li>
</ul>, <ul class="tags tags--project">
<li><a href="/processes/mes-idees-pour-mon-quartier/f/472/budgets/3/projects?filter%5Bcategory_id%5D%5B%5D=80" title="Filtrer les résultats de la catégorie : Nature en ville"><span class="show-for-sr">Filtrer les résultats de la catégorie : Nature en ville</span><span aria-hidden="true">Nature en ville</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/processes/mes-idees-pour-mon-quartier/f/472/budgets/3/projects?filter%5Bscope_id%5D%5B%5D=66" title="Filtrer les résultats pour le secteur : 2.4 - Casselardit / Fontaine-Bayonne / Cartoucherie"><span class="show-for-sr">Filtrer les résultats pour le secteur : 2.4 - Casselardit / Fontaine-Bayonne / Cartoucherie</span><span aria-hidden="true">2.4 - Casselardit / Fontaine-Bayonne / Cartoucherie</span></a></li>
</ul>,........
```

I am interested in extracting the objects that come after `title="...."` but I am not sure what is the most efficient way to do so. Since they are inside `<li>` I tried something like `soup.find_all('ul',class_='tags tags--project').find_all('li')` but that does not work. Do you have any suggestions?

PS: As you can see from the example above, normally inside each `ul` you have four `title="...."` but the second two are just repetitions of technically I just need to keep the first two.

Comment: Please clarify *normally inside each ul you have four title="...."* - Why does your example only have two per `<ul>` and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to get text from the different `<span>`s under `<ul>`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """\
<ul class="tags tags--project">
    <li>
        <a href="/processes/mes-idees-pour-mon-quartier/f/472/budgets/3/projects?filter%5Bcategory_id%5D%5B%5D=80" title="Filtrer les résultats de la catégorie : Nature en ville">
            <span class="show-for-sr">Filtrer les résultats de la catégorie : Nature en ville</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true">Nature en ville</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/processes/mes-idees-pour-mon-quartier/f/472/budgets/3/projects?filter%5Bscope_id%5D%5B%5D=71" title="Filtrer les résultats pour le secteur : 4.2 - Jolimont / Soupetard / Roseraie / Gloire / Gramont / Amouroux">
            <span class="show-for-sr">Filtrer les résultats pour le secteur : 4.2 - Jolimont / Soupetard / Roseraie / Gloire / Gramont / Amouroux</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true">4.2 - Jolimont / Soupetard / Roseraie / Gloire / Gramont / Amouroux</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="tags tags--project">
    <li>
        <a href="/processes/mes-idees-pour-mon-quartier/f/472/budgets/3/projects?filter%5Bcategory_id%5D%5B%5D=80" title="Filtrer les résultats de la catégorie : Nature en ville">
            <span class="show-for-sr">Filtrer les résultats de la catégorie : Nature en ville</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true">Nature en ville</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/processes/mes-idees-pour-mon-quartier/f/472/budgets/3/projects?filter%5Bscope_id%5D%5B%5D=66" title="Filtrer les résultats pour le secteur : 2.4 - Casselardit / Fontaine-Bayonne / Cartoucherie">
            <span class="show-for-sr">Filtrer les résultats pour le secteur : 2.4 - Casselardit / Fontaine-Bayonne / Cartoucherie</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true">2.4 - Casselardit / Fontaine-Bayonne / Cartoucherie</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for ul in soup.select("ul.tags.tags--project"):
    for span in ul.select("span"):
        print(span.text)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Filtrer les résultats de la catégorie : Nature en ville
Nature en ville
Filtrer les résultats pour le secteur : 4.2 - Jolimont / Soupetard / Roseraie / Gloire / Gramont / Amouroux
4.2 - Jolimont / Soupetard / Roseraie / Gloire / Gramont / Amouroux
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Filtrer les résultats de la catégorie : Nature en ville
Nature en ville
Filtrer les résultats pour le secteur : 2.4 - Casselardit / Fontaine-Bayonne / Cartoucherie
2.4 - Casselardit / Fontaine-Bayonne / Cartoucherie
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

If you want every second one, you can use `[::2]`:

```py
for ul in soup.select("ul.tags.tags--project"):
    for span in ul.select("span")[::2]:     # <-- use [::2] here
        print(span.text)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Filtrer les résultats de la catégorie : Nature en ville
Filtrer les résultats pour le secteur : 4.2 - Jolimont / Soupetard / Roseraie / Gloire / Gramont / Amouroux
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Filtrer les résultats de la catégorie : Nature en ville
Filtrer les résultats pour le secteur : 2.4 - Casselardit / Fontaine-Bayonne / Cartoucherie
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrej! Another question. Could I adapt this code to only obtain the {Filtrer les résultats de la catégorie : Nature en ville}, and separately. I thought about using [0::1] as you did in the example above but that did not do the work.

Comment: Oh... [0::4] did the trick!